# sed partial replace or variable

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I'd like to use sed to do a replace, but not by searching for what to replace.

Allow me to explain. I have a variable set to a default value initially.

```
VARIABLE="DEFAULT"
```

I can do a sed to replace DEFAULT with what I want, but then I would have to put DEFAULT back when I was all done. This is becuase what gets stored to VARIABLE is unique to the user. I'd like to use sed to search for somthing else other than what to replace. For example, search for VARIABLE=" and " and replace whats between it. That way it just constantly updates and there is no need to reset VARIABLE.

This is how I do it currently:

I call the script and pass an argument

```
./script 123456789
```

Inside the script, this is what happens:

```
sed -i "s%DEFAULT%$1%" file_to_modify
```

This replaces

```
VARIABLE="DEFAULT"
```

with

```
VARIABLE="123456789"
```

It would be nice if I didn't have to search for "DEFAULT", because then I would not have to reset VARIABLE at end of script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/VARIABLE="[^"]*"/VARIABLE="123456789"/' file_to_modify
```

Or, more generally:

```
sed -r 's/VARIABLE="[^"]*"/VARIABLE="'"$1"'"/'  file_to_modify
```

Both of the above use a regular expression that looks for 'VARIABLE="anything-at-all"' and replaces it with, in the first example above 'VARIABLE="123456789"' or, in the second, 'VARIABLE="$1"' where "$1" is the first argument to your script.  The key element is `[^"]`.  It means any character other than double-quote.  `[^"]*` means any number of characters other than double-quote.  Thus, we replace whatever was in the double-quotes before, `"[^"]*"`, with our new value `"123456789"` or, in the second case, `"$1"`.

The second case is a bit tricky.  We want to substitute `$1` into the expression but the expression is itself in single quotes.  Inside single-quotes, bash will not substitute for `$1`.  So, the sed command is broken up into three parts:

```
# spaces added for exposition but don't try to use it this way
's/VARIABLE="[^"]*"/VARIABLE="'  "$1"   '"/'
```

The first part is in single quotes and bash passes it literally to sed.  The second part is in double-quotes, so bash will subsitute in for the value of `$``.  The third part is in single-quotes and gets passed to sed literally.

**MORE:**  Here is a simple way to test this approach on the command line without depending on any files:

```
$ new=1234 ; echo 'VARIABLE="DEFAULT"' | sed -r 's/VARIABLE="[^"]*"/VARIABLE="'"$new"'"/'
VARIABLE="1234"
```

The first line above is the command run at the prompt (`$`).  The second is the output from running the command..

Comment: Can you add a little explanation please?

Comment: I tried sed -r 's/VARIABLE="([^"]*)"/VARIABLE="$1"/' file_to_modify and the script freezes

Comment: Do you need the parenthesis around the brackets? I think you could also use `'s/VARIABLE="[^"]*"/VARIABLE="123456789"/'`

Comment: Either way, the script still freezes trying to do the sed

Comment: @Atomiklan Does the explanation in the updated answer cover it?

Comment: @Atomiklan What do you mean by "freeze"?  sed will appear to freeze if you don't give it input.  It works for me.

Comment: @Atomiklan: Try the command *without* the script. If that works, try writing a *very* simple script that will invoke the command. If that fails, show us the script and how you call it.

Comment: Yes this worked. Thank you. sed was not freezing, it was actually one line above that was waiting for input that didn't exist. Only change I had to make to your code was changing sed -r to sed -i. Not sure of the differences between the attributes (I'm sure huge), but sed -i behaves as expected. Thanks again